# Developed app with navigation menu, it shows "Unfortunately App name Has Stopped" even before opening app

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have developed app with sliding navigation menu. it doesnt contain any error in the project. I have successfully build signed apk but after installing it on phone it shows "unfortunately Appname has stopped" even before opening the app.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wAashiqeRasool.HamareNabi" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.wAashiqeRasool.HamareNabi.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.wAashiqeRasool.HamareNabi;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//initializing WebView
private WebView mwebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
  findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
 R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //WebView
    mwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //improve webView performance

mwebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

mwebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mwebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


    mwebView.loadUrl("www.hamarenabi.in?m=1");
    //force links open in webview only
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_us) {
        // Handle the camera action
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.hamarenabi.in/search/label/Asma-E-
Husna?m=1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_world) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.hamarenabi.in/p/nikah-in-islam-
assalamu-alaikum-wa.html?m=1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_tech) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.hamarenabi.in/search/label/aqaid-e-
ahle%20sunnat?m=1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_sports) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.hamarenabi.in/p/ramzan.html?m=1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.hamarenabi.in/p/contact.html?m=1");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://www.hamarenabi.in/p/contact-us.html?m=1");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.hamarenabi.in?m=1")) {
            //open url contents in webview
            return false;
        } else {
            //here open external links in external browser or app
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
    //ProgressDialogue
    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        pd.setMessage("Website is Loading..");
        pd.show();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
//goto previous page when pressing back button

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mwebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mwebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Build.Gradle (Modular App):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wAashiqeRasool.HamareNabi"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: What made you think that you shouldn't post the error log?

Comment: Logcat Errors: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6a1Wje6UpUXUUs1TVVYT2xWZGs/view?usp=sharing Please help me sir. I will lose my efforts.

Comment: you are loading huge image from drawable.

Comment: Reduced size of all icons to 72×72piels. But still it's showing same problem. App size reduced 50%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is because the variable 'pd' is null in your onPageFinished() call. Add a null check as shown below and you won't see any crash in onPageFinished().

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if( pd != null )
            pd.dismiss();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
```

Comment: Your code already has onPageFinished() method. Just modify it to what I have shown.

Comment: You are genius sir. Thank you very much for your help. But one problem is all the links are opening in external browser instead of opening in app.

Comment: Glad it fixed your crash. Please accept the answer. Also post your code that opens the URL. Will see what's going wrong in that. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted all codes above. Webview settings are in Main Activity. Please check and Reply. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate your work.

Comment: In your code only if the URL is  "www.hamarenabi.in?m=1" then the URL is opened in the webview inside your app. Otherwise the app opens the URL in external browser. Change your method shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) to always return true if you want all the URLs to be loaded within your app.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir. I tried many times but all the links are opening in external browser. I can't understand how to fix this. I have marked your answer as best. Have a great day ahead.